# Trailhead - "Using the Report Builder" challenge. "Stage" field not available in reporting?

Tags: reporting, filters, trailhead

I'm doing trailhead "Using the Report Builder" module and I'm stuck on the challenge since I cannot add Stage as a Filter and I don't know wth is going on. 
Anyone went trough this?.

[image]

Thanks!, Nahuel

Comment: I can see Stage under "fields section" on the left panel, did you search for stage in the drop down (or) drag and drop the stage field as one of your filter criteria

Comment: You do not need Won and closed filters, have 2 filters 1) Amount > 25000 2) Stage "not equal to" "closed won, closed lost".

Comment: I was searching in the dropdown, and had to drag and drop. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to drag and drop Stage field from the left panel onto Filters area (make sure there is no any filter in edit mode before trying this)

Comment: Thanks!, It was the UI not being intuitive. When I selected "Add Filter" and Field as a filter it did not show Stage as an option, but drag drop from left panel worked!. Thank you!